# Importing .CSS files into ionic 2 Apps

Tags: javascript, css, angular, jquery-ui, ionic2

i am doing an app with Ionic 2 Angular 2 and Typescript and i need to import some .CSS files of Jquery UI. I needed the datepicker form JqueryUI but i also need to import CSS files to make it look and feel as wanted.

I need the imports to be global since i use the datepicker in different pages, so i added an import statement in app.scss in the app folder and it worked, on browser only.
When i compile in production mode i get `" Broken @import statement "`error which i didn't understand.

So does anyone know how to properly import the external CSS files for Jquery UI or is there anyway to fix the Broken @import error ?

thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this is the same scenario, but you can take a look at [this github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/712)

Comment: Well actually that is it, i had to add the ImportProcess:false option and it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Do you mind if I add it as the answer, so we can close the issue?

Comment: Yes i'll accept the answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/712), the cause of the problem seems to be the `clean-css` module.

One way to fix it, would be to add

```
module.exports = {
    options:{
      processImport:false
  }
};
```

to `./node_modules/config/cleancss.config.js`.